# Can I reserve one core to system only?

Tags: windows-10, intel-core-i7, multi-core

I have a workflow where it sometimes renders my system unresponsive or slow. I deal with that by setting affinity of such demanding apps to only a handful of cores/threads (Core i7).

Now I am looking for a way to automate that or even set it in such way that system can only run on a dedicated core and/or at least all (future) apps can only run on all other cores.

Comment: I'd be looking at running the hungry process in a VM, where you can limit its performance to exactly the number of real cores you have & that will always leave enough for other processes to use. It's how I've always done compiling or video compression, so there's no delay in my other work. If you've enough RAM & cores it really does speed everything up.

Comment: @Tetsujin Wow, that is an interesting concept. I shall keep this on mind. However, it's not suitable for my particular use case - software development, where I depend on multitude of apps and tools and multi-task a lot - switching desktops, multiple monitors, etc.

Comment: Horses for courses, indeed - personally I just throw the hard task at the VM [which can often be a simple duplicate of my 'main' environment, or sometimes a trimmed-back version. But as it's right there I can quickly throw files in & out of it without much wait [so long as 'space', RAM, Drive, etc isn't an issue - I have 64GB RAM, 2 1TB SSDs & 14TB HD in here & 2 6-core Xeons, so I'm rarely stuck for room to breathe ;)